# How to convert UTC hours to local using Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

I want to convert UTC hours to local time using JavaScript it is possible ?

I have last 24 hours in array

```
let _arrHours = ["4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","1","2","3"]
```

I read this question [Convert Hour UTC to Local using moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55029286/convert-hour-utc-to-local-using-moment-js)

It's possible using simple JavaScript ?

I have try to fix it but it's works only India time ? what do for other countries ?

```
  let _arrHours = ["4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "1", "2", "3"];
    let _arrDt = [];
    for (let t = 0; t < _arrHours.length; t++) {
      let tm = _arrHours[t];
      tm = parseInt(tm) + 5.5; //indian timezone, I want to do it dynamic country wise !
      if (tm > 24) {
        tm = tm - 24;
      }
      else if (tm < 0) {
        tm = tm + 24;
      }
      _arrDt.push(tm);
    }

    console.log(_arrDt, '_arrDt');
```

Comment: I would highly suggest you to either use the moment.js NodeJS package, or its script for html, to do these, since moment makes everything simple

Comment: You can do it using `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` you can get `offset` then convert into hour !

Try this code it's help you !

```
 let offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset(); //get the country wise offset !
    if (offset > 0) { //let's convert in to hour
      offset = (-Math.abs(offset / 60));
    } else {
      offset = (Math.abs(offset / 60));
    }
    let _arrHours = ["4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "1", "2", "3"];
    let _arrDt = [];
    for (let t = 0; t < _arrHours.length; t++) {
      let tm = _arrHours[t];
      tm = parseInt(tm) + offset;
      if (tm > 24) {
        tm = tm - 24;
      }
      else if (tm < 0) {
        tm = tm + 24;
      }
      _arrDt.push(tm);
    }

    console.log(_arrDt, '_arrDt');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use **toLocaleTimeString** to get local time

let assume you UTC hours is **17**

```
let UTCTime=17:00;

var LocalTime=new Date('2021-09-23T'+ UTCTime+ "z").toLocaleTimeString()
```

Comment: But i have only last 24 hours array

Comment: In case of array, you can use foreach and store new UTC time in another array